# Is it possible to retrieve SQL error codes from unsuccessful entity framework data operations?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, error-code

SQL returns codes that are preceded by a minus sign (-) indicate that the SQL statement execution was unsuccessful. (All SQL defined error codes are negative integers).

In previous applications, I have used a stored procedure based SQL data layer that checks for these error codes and translates them into user friendly error messages which are then displayed to the end user.

I have been testing the validity of replacing the old stored procedure based system for a system based around the Entity Framework. The only problem that I have come across so far is that I can't find any way to retrieve the SQL error codes that explain any database related operation failures. After extensive searching online and finding nothing, I figured that someone here has to know the answer.

So my simple question is... is there any way that I can access the SQL error codes from each SQL statement execution when using the Entity Framework?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can catch the `SqlException` wich has detailed informations about your exception.

```
try
{
   // do your changes
   myDbContext.SaveChanges();
}
catch (SqlException ex)
{
    // ex.LineNumber
    // ex.ErrorCode
    foreach (SqlError error in ex.Errors)
    {
        // error.LineNumber
    }
}
```

More informations about [SqlException Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception.aspx)

**hope this helps**